# What kind of misfire instruction I need to set for ImmediateTrigger?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, misfire-instruction

I want to execute only 5 jobs at the same time. And if the job can't start due of lacking of free threads, I want it to start when the free thread will appear, and only one time. 
This is my code:

```
SchedulerFactory schedFact = new org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory("quartz.properties");
sched = schedFact.getScheduler();
sched.start();
String jobName = generateJobDetailName();
JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail(jobName, GRP_Immediate, MyJob.class);
jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put(MyJob.DATA, data);
Trigger trigger = TriggerUtils.makeImmediateTrigger(0, 0);
trigger.setName(jobName + "_Simpletrigger");
sched.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

And this is my `quartz.properties` file:

```
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
```

But there is something I can't understand. What kind of `misfire instruction` I need to set for required behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/SimpleTrigger.html#MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW) (note that your Trigger is a SimpleTrigger):

```
trigger.setMisfireInstruction(SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW);
```

since you have a 'one-shot' trigger that should be executed exactly ones as early as possible.